# BigQuery web UI is unresponsive & eventually crashes

Tags: google-bigquery

When I click on "Details" to see a preview of the data in the table, the web UI locks up and I see the following errors. I've tried refreshing and restating my browser, but it doesn't help.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, we (the BQ team) are aware of performance issues when viewing very repeated rows in the BigQuery web UI.  The public genomics tables are known to tickle these performance issues since individual rows of their table are highly repeated.

We're considering a few methods of fixing this, but the simplest would probably be to default to the JSON display of rows for problematic tables, and allow switching to the tabular view with a "View it at your own risk!"-style warning message.

Answer (score 0):

It took a little time for me too, but it eventually (1min 40sec) loaded up to UI.
I think it is because of how table data is presented in Native BQ UI for Preview mode.
As you could noticed - it is showed in sort of hierarchical way.

[image]

I noticed this slowness for heavy tables (row size and/or hierarchical structure wise) when this was intorduced. And btw. only one row is showed for this particular table because of this.

Of course this is just my guess - would be great to hear from Google Team!

Meantime - when I am using internal application that uses same APIs for preview table data  - i dont see any slowness at all (10 rows in 3 sec), which supports my above guess.

[image]

Comment: Nice UI app, is that available as open source or for public?

Comment: Thank you! This one not yet, but BigQuery Mate chrome extension is free and available for public on Chrome Web Store - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bigquery-mate/nepgdloeceldecnoaaegljlichnfognh

Comment: it is available now for public - check out https://potens.io/ and/or https://potensio.zendesk.com/